# Karma Runner Unable To Identify Moment Timezone In AngularJS App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, momentjs

I had `moment.js` included previously on my `Karma.conf.js` which works fine. Recently, I have included `moment-timezone.js` library using bower and added dependency files in `karma.conf.js`. After this steps all of the specs are failing, due to undefined state of setDefault method of timezone in `moment.tz.setDefault("Asia/Singapore");` . Please note, moment-timezone works fine when running in browser.

Could you please help to me to fix the issue in Karma Config?

Attached `karma.conf.js` file snippet 
[image]

Comment: Can you include more information around this error? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: I have defined ` moment.tz.setDefault("Asia/Singapore");` in `app.js` to make default timezone to Singapore.When I run my specs using Karma, it throws the following error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDefault' of undefined" from Angular-mocks. @mikwat

Comment: Can you provide the code for `app.js` and your karma spec?

Comment: It's simple, I have just setup the global default timezone in `app.js` and ran the specs which I had already written (the test cases were passed as well before I included the moment timezone)

Comment: I am seeing this issue anyone figured it out?